JIRA Cloud Server - Any way to write JQL to capture status change "destination owner" at time of status change?
In our (and I assume many others') process flows JIRA items can change assignment on a frequent basis, so we need to track whom the "target" was when an item changed statuses.
Is there a way to structure the JQL so that it will report on whom the redirected JIRA item went to?
In other words, here's an example path:

Developer 1 is working a JIRA, moves it to "Status #1 (let's call it "Ready for Testing") and assigns it to a QA individual

QA finds an issue and sends it back to Developer 1, changing the Assignee in the process back to Developer 1 and the status to "In Development"

Developer 1 reviews the issue and determines that it needs to be addressed by a different individual (Developer 2) and assigns it to Developer 2

Rinse and repeat until issue is fully resolved


For the above, we are trying to track whom the issue went to in step two above instead of whomever the issue ultimately ended up being assigned to. Is there a JQL that will allow us to retrieve this "at the time of transition" information?
